# Databricks sql - Insert multiple rows using python list values

Tags: python, databricks-sql

I have a list of values -
['a', 'b', 'c']

I have a delta table. Consider below one as an example -

[image]

I am iterating a dataframe in a for loop and constructed the above list from dataframe result. And first column value is hardcoded value. So, in for loop, I will pass the values from list and execute as multiple insert statements.

```
spark.sql("insert into default.test values(1, 'a')")
spark.sql("insert into default.test values(1, 'b')")
spark.sql("insert into default.test values(1, 'c')")
```

How to execute a single insert statement so that I will get the below one -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html#examples) has an example on how to insert multiple rows with one insert statement.

So in your case, it will be

`spark.sql("insert into default.test values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')")`

Answer (score -1):

The question has a lot of ambiguity. E.g. How do you expect the `Rule` and the `name` to be matched up in the output table?

But maybe this will help get you started.

First turn the python into a DataFrame and add it to the SQL context:

```
%python
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x = spark.createDataFrame([(1, vals)], ('Rule', 'name'))
x.createOrReplaceTempView("x")
```

Then you can use SQL on it:

```
%sql
select Rule, explode(name) as name from x
```